# I want to define argument

Tags: logic

I was making a logical system. My metalanguage is English (the problem is related to English as well). I want to define an argument. Note:

1.) I don't want to define what is a valid argument, I will define it once I define what is an argument.

2.) I don't want the assertion that *the premises look as if they are supporting the conclusion*, because this will result me in asking what is supporting which only complicate things.

3.) I want to have the option that my conclusion may belong to the set of premises.

So, I will define

> **A collection of statements and a statement(which may or may not belong to the collection) are together called an Argument**.

> Here the statement is called conclusion and the statements belonging to the collection is called premises.

My question is have I done it right? Is there anything I can add? And is my definition vague?

Comment: Foxes have no tails. The sky is red. Ice cream is yummy. There, an argument.

Comment: Yes; an *argument* is a pair $(\Gamma, \varphi)$ where the set $\Gamma$ of statements is the set of *premises* and the statement $\varphi$ is the *conclusion*.